Can´t find way to undelete ext4 directory
Per accident I shift+deleted a folder with subfolders from a 2nd disk on my machine (Ubuntu 24.04 / ext4 filesystem). I searched on how to un-delete the directory + files but without success. This happenned about 24 hours ago.
Steps I took:

In order to preserve the disk, no new files have been copied or
deleted from this 2nd disk (/dev/sdc1).
Unmounted /dev/sdc1
Ran the extundelete command below, it shows no recoverable inodes
Prepared a rescatux live USB stick and ran testdisk, also didn´t
find anything to recover

Is there a way to recover the deleted files, or are they lost for good?
Output of the extundelete command:
xxx:~$ sudo extundelete --restore-all --after $(date -d "-30 hours" +%s) /dev/sdc1
[sudo] password for xxx: 
Only show and process deleted entries if they are deleted on or after 1725723177 and before 9223372036854775807.
NOTICE: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 15746 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 0 descriptors loaded.
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory / ... 
0 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
0 recoverable inodes still lost.
No files were undeleted.


Nope, nothing was written since shift+delete

@JoepvanSteen, thx for recommednig UFS Explorer. I tried it out, and gave mixed results. It found all the deleted files, but has them all listed with size 0 bytes.
Any additional tips?

You said, "Ubuntu" and "Shift Delete".  So I assume you are using the GNOME desktop?   If you are using GNOME, it simulates the Trash Can functionality ala MacOS by not actually deleting the file or folder, and instead moving it to the "Trash Can Folder".  So you might be able to "undelete" the Folder by just moving the files from the "Trash Can" back to the original place.
Now, if you emptied the Trash Can, or you deleted the file or folders via the command line, there is a very high probability that the data is lost forever.  Yes, there are some extreme tools that you can use to try to do data recovery, but that's why you regularly run disk backups, right?  :-)

SHIFT+DELETE do NOT send files to the trash can.

I had a backup on an external USB HDD via plain copy/paste. The sad thing is that I was working on syncing the original + backups and deleting some old files when I got interrupted. Then, when resuming I didn't pay enough attention and hit shit+delete on both the original AND the backup :-(.
I checked the trash can and it is empty.
